# replacing a row in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have the following two arrays:

```
int [][]nums={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int []sums= {44,45,46};
```

I want to replace 7 8 9 of nums with 44 45 46 of sums. This is what I am currently doing:

```
for(int i=0; i<sums.length; i++){
  for(int j=0 ; j< nums[2].length; j++){
    nums[2][j]=sums[i];
  } 
}
```

However, this makes nums[2]={46,46,46}
Can someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could do just `nums[2] = sums;`.

Comment: Hint: Your last iteration of the parent loop is assigning sums[2]  to all nums[2][ ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loops in this case. You could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
    nums[2][i] = sums[i];
}
```

Or you could assign it directly with no loop:

```
int[][] nums = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
int[] sums = {44,45,46};
nums[2] = sums;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(nums));
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [44, 45, 46]]
```

The difference is that the first solution will copy the elements from `sums` to `nums[2]`, while the second solution will make `nums[2]` reference the same object as `sums`. So if you choose the second option and change `sums` later, `nums[2]` will also change.